# Specifically handle bot requests for pages that don't exist, or allow them to 404?

Tags: security, bots

I get requests for pages that don't exist in my website that are clearly bots looking for security holes. Requests for /administrator/index.php for example, and the site isn't written in PHP.

Is it a better security practice to handle the common requests with a Forbidden or something specific? Or just let them 404?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a massive difference from a security perspective. Forbidden may lead them to think they're on the right lines and try more, 404 may lead them to try other things.

If you can, just don't reply, so the connection times out, because this is the most costly thing for attackers - time. If you reply immediately they can try again immediately, but if they're waiting for a response... Obviously if this takes up resources for you then it isn't a good idea.

If you can blacklist the IP address and just terminate any request immediately when it comes in that's also good, though you may want to add a couple of grace requests before doing that...

Comment: That makes sense. I like the idea of letting the connection time out, but not sure I want to get into having to monitor for excessive demand on the server. It would be fun to send them into a really slow redirect loop, though.

Comment: Interesting idea to return a page which redirects to itself